# How do "directory VIEWS" auto-update their file list?

Tags: operating-system, view, refresh

I am just curious about this.

I had a network folder open on one computer viewing the files in the folder. From another computer I opened the same folder on the network and deleted a file. On the first computer the deleted file immediate disappeared from the list.

The only way that I can think of how it knows that is that it is constantly checking the contents of the open folder. But that sounds like it would waste a lot of resources to do, but I cannot think of any other way it could do that. So I was just wondering...how does that work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a push notification. Rather that the client computer constantly checking, the server sends a message to the client when a change is made.

Answer (score 0):

You never specified what platform you're interested in. In general, the only thing that is portable is polling to see when a file or directory has been updated. Polling once a second or so is generally not too expensive, though over a network file system it may be too much.

Various platforms offer a variety of solutions for being notified when filesystems change. Moder versions of Linux provide [`inotify`](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify.html). Mac OS X provides [the FSEvent system](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). On Windows there is a [directory change notification system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365261(VS.85).aspx).